# Problem when capturing text between two letters

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the following regular expression to get text between `/*` and `*/`:

```
(/\*)+(.+)(\*/)
```

this works fine when this only needs to happen once e.g the whole string is just

```
/* hello */
it only needs to capture once
```

but if there is more than one time where it needs to be captured it grabs what ever is in between for example:

```
/* hello */
it only needs to capture more than once [THIS ALSO GET'S HIGHLIGHTED]
/* second time */
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: See also the answer to your Frequently Asked Question http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're telling it to. By default, regexp's are *greedy*, meaning that they will match the longest thing they can.

In Perl regexp, you can override that behaviour by

```
(/\*)+(.+?)(\*/)
```

The '?' tells the '+' to match the shortest string it can, instead of the longest.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using greedy matching between the comment delimiters.  Try this instead

```
(/\*)+(.+?)(\*/)
```